# URL-Rewriting won't allow reg-ex as first paramater in address

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, helicontech

I am using Helicon Ape in IIS7 for my 'mod rewrite' on Windows Server 2008.

Very simple rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([^\/]+) /index.php?page=$1 [L,NC]
www.example.com/mypage
```

This doesn't work, and I have experienced this on several sites. However, I have reached a problem where I am now transferring an existing site (with the above rule, which previously worked in IIS6, without Helicon Ape) to a new server, so I need to get it to work.

If I add an explicit parameter to my .htaccess before the regular-expression, it works fine:

```
RewriteRule ^page/([^\/]+) /index.php?page=$1 [L,NC]
www.example.com/page/mypage
```

I don't understand why this works and the previous example doesn't?

Comment: Perhaps it requires a leading slash? Considering that you do not allow them in your captures...

Comment: I have tried every variation I can think of in regards to slashes and syntax, but I can't get it to accept the regex as the leading parameter. Have even tried using `(.*)` for the regex.

Comment: As it stands it is returning `['page'] => 'index.php'`.

Comment: Weird indeed... And I don't think it has anything to do with the leading slash in the destination pattern. What happens when you try `RewriteRule ^ index.php?page=$0 [L,NC]` - just to test? (Or have you already tried that?)

Comment: Using `$0` returns index.php still. I have managed to return the correct values by adding QSA: `RewriteRule ^([^\/]+) /index.php?page=$1 [L,NC,QSA]`. I'm no htaccess wizard though and not completely sure what it's doing, as even though it is now returning the values, the website is not behaving the same as it does when I add `^page/` to the beginning of the string. I'm not sure how QSA differs?

Comment: Have you tried to enable logging in httpd.conf by uncommenting "RewriteLogLevel 9" line? You can see how the URL is processed by Ape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following redirects `/mypage` or `/mypage/` to `/index.php?page=mypage`

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1 [L,NC]
```

You were escaping the `/` but it's not required. (Only `\` does.)

Comment: Thank you. This works. A little too late for the site I was working on as I've already been through and changed the links! But it has been a repetitive problem for me, so it will help in future.